# How to publish a wpf application in windows tablet

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a wpf app. I want to publish my app to Windows tablet.

These were the steps I did:

1. Right click on project
2. Click publish
3. Provide a path to publish

Then it has generated files to install – I have tried to install the generated manifest file in both published machine and tablet.  I can see my app in "add/remove", but when I open the app from the Start menu my app is not initiated. It's not displaying anything.

Thanks,

Punith

Comment: Show us, your manifest file.

Comment: As I recall, Windows tablet is pretty the same as PC. maybe you missed something else.

Comment: It could be a install path problem or something like that. So I've asked about manifest file.